# Problem sending data from the controller to the view in spring mvc and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to learn spring mvc and hibernate, so I am doing a C.R.U.D. about sports olympics. I have two tables in my database, one is called 
Player and another called Sport.

Tools: Netbeans 8.0.2, GlassFish Server 4.1, Java EE 7 web, Spring web MVC 4.0.1, Hibernate 4.3.1

Problem: In the index page, I need to show the number of registered players and the number of registered sports. I do it using a select count and in my controller I try to send the data to the index using the get method, but none of the data is shown in the index.htm, it seems not to obey the controller.
but the index page can be seen in the browser.

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
                <prop key="rdeporte.htm">homeController</prop>
                <prop key="rjugador.htm">homeController</prop>
                <prop key="ujugador.htm">homeController</prop>
                <prop key="udeporte.htm">homeController</prop>
                <prop key="borrardeporte.htm">homeController</prop> 
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="homeController" class="Controlador.HomeController"></bean>
    <bean name="indexController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController" p:viewName="index" />    
</beans>
```

Index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="es">


      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>Welcome to Insert with Spring Web MVC project</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <!--    <div class="container">-->
             <div class="row" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.1)">
                 <div class="col-lg-2">
                     <div class="container">
                         <div class="row">
                         <div class="h-25 d-inline-block" style="text-align:center;font-size:24px;width:100%;height: 50%;background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.1)">OPTIONS</div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="row" style="width:100%;padding-top:15%;">

                         </div>
                         <div class="row">
                             <a href="rjugador.htm"><img style="width:100%;height:auto;" src="<c:url value="/resources/img/btnrp.png"/>" alt="Registration of participants"></a>
                         </div>
                         <div class="row">
                             <a href="rdeporte.htm"><img style="width:100%;height:auto;" src="<c:url value="/resources/img/btnrd.png"/>" alt="register new disciplines"></a>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">

                      <div class="card border-danger" style="width:100%;height:auto;">
                               <img class="card-img-top" style="width:100%;height:auto;" src="<c:url value="/resources/img/resSports.png"/>" alt="Card image cap">
                          <div class="card-header bg-danger">
                              <h4 style="font-size:auto;">Raccoon city Sports Olimpics</h4>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-2">

                 </div>
            </div>
    <!--    </div>-->
            <div class="container-fluid" style="text-align:center;">
                <h2>ESTADISTICS</h2>
            </div>


                    <div class="row">  
                        <div class="navItem" style="font-size:auto; text-align:center;">
                              <div class="card" style="width: 100%; float: ">
                                  <img class="card-img-top" src="<c:url value="/resources/img/cabecerap.png"/>" alt="Card image cap">
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="card-text">   
                                            <p>Players:</p><c:out value="${ numPlayers }"/>
                                        </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="navItem" style="font-size:auto; text-align:center;">
                              <div class="card" style="width: 100%; float: ">
                                  <img class="card-img-top" src="<c:url value="/resources/img/cabecerad.png"/>" alt="Card image cap">
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                      <div class="card-text">   
                                            <p>Sports:</p>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <p>something</p>
                </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

```
package Controlador;
@Controller
public class HomeController {

        /* this controller does not want to work */
        @RequestMapping(value="index.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView index(){
            ModelAndView mav= new ModelAndView();
            Estadistics est=new Estadistics();
            mav.addObject("numPlayers",est.getNumPlayers());
            mav.setViewName("index");
            return mav;
        }

    @RequestMapping(value="rjugador.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView rjugador(){
     /***Other Controlers***/
       .......................
}
```

```
package Controlador;

public class Estadistics {

    public int getNumPlayers (){

        int c=queries("select count(j) from Player as j");

        return c;
    }

  public int queries(String hql) {

        int num=0;
        try
        {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
            applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            SessionFactory session = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

                Session ses;
                ses=session.openSession();


                Query q=ses.createQuery(hql);
                num = q.getFirstResult();


                ses.close();

        }catch(HibernateException ex){

        }
     return num;

    }    
}
```

the query works
https://drive.google.com/open?id=13khiwcVJ2sS0qn49LAG4m3s00nlzVIBX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start reviewing your mapping, it seems like your dispatcher is waiting for .jsp, and you haven't.

Could you please share your complete JSP file?

It will be good to also check if your query is actually returning something. You can add some log to print the number before sending it to your view.

Check out this example:[SimplerUrlHandlerMapping](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springmvc/springmvc_simpleurlhandlermapping.htm)

Comment: Sorry, I have already made the changes, even though I think the error is in how I am doing the index controller apparently does not become equal to this, now the question is how should I do an explicit mapping controller? :(

Comment: You should use the <annotation-driven /> and also the <context:component-scan base-package="{your_controller_base_package}" /> doing that you can avoid the simple handler mapping config that you have in place. Check out this example: https://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I was doing some wrong things.

in the methods

getNumPlayers and queries the type of return must be of type Long because the number of records in the databases can be very large the type of return suitable for an account is Long and not int.

Second, to solve the problem with the controller, another additional controller must be created, one that deals with the mapping and the other with the sending of parameters.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1URYfXxsDBxijKRu-_B3jlJS7BO-4TCfX